# How to proceed with flutter app to display outputs from deep learning model?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-platform, deployment, google-colaboratory, flutter-web

I have trained a model which takes a pointcloud as input and outputs the bounding boxes on Images on google colab.

Now, I want to build a flutter app where the inputs(pointcloud) will be uploaded and gets the output image as result.

I have explored the use of tflite,but it doesn't support some of the tensorflow operations.

I can think of two solutions.

1)I wish I could connect my flutter app to google colab,run the cells and save the output to my drive from where I could return it to my flutter app. Is this possible? If so,how can I do it?

2. Using Google Cloud Platform. There are wide range of tools available in GCP and I have no idea which one to use. Can I know the possible and easy to implement ways?

Kindly share your thoughts on How I need to proceed.

Comment: Your first option might not work as colab instances are temporary and are not meant to serve models. Your second option is the right direction in IMHO. But this cannot be answered here in stackoverflow. GCP and any such cloud based solution definitely has a steep leaning curve. But you will always find solutions. Search for tensorflow serving. Another option you might consider is TensorflowJs.

Comment: Thanks. Thought Using cloud would be easy,realized it isn't. Very long road ahead to complete my Project